# Variable not changing in pomodoro clock

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

```
function App() {
  const [displayTime, setDisplayTime] = React.useState(2 * 6);
  const [breakTime, setBreakTime] = React.useState(5 * 6);
  const [sessionTime, setSessionTime] = React.useState(2 * 6);
  const [timerOn, setTimerOn] = React.useState(false);
  const [onBreak, setOnBreak] = React.useState(false);
  const [breakAudio, setBreakAudio] = useState(new Audio("breakTime.mp3"));

  const controlTime = () => {
    let second = 1000;
    let date = new Date().getTime();
    let nextDate = new Date().getTime() + second;
    let onBreakVar = onBreak;
    if (!timerOn) {
      let interval = setInterval(() => {
        date = new Date().getTime();
        if (date > nextDate) {
          setDisplayTime((prev) => {
            if (prev <= 0 && !onBreakVar) {
              //playBreakAudio();
              onBreakVar = true;
              setOnBreak(true);
              return breakTime;
            } else if (prev <= 0 && onBreakVar) {
              //playBreakAudio();
              onBreakVar = false;
              setOnBreak(false);
              return sessionTime;
            }
            return prev - 1;
          });
          nextDate += second;
        }
      }, 30);
      localStorage.clear();
      localStorage.setItem("interval-id", interval);
    }
    if (timerOn) {
      clearInterval(localStorage.getItem("interval-id"));
    }
    setTimerOn(!timerOn);
  };
  return (
    <div className="clock">
      <h1>Pomodoro Clock</h1>
      <div className="container">
        <Length
          title={"break length"}
          changeTime={changeTime}
          type={"break"}
          time={breakTime}
          formatTime={formatTime}
        />
        <Length
          title={"session length"}
          changeTime={changeTime}
          type={"session"}
          time={sessionTime}
          formatTime={formatTime}
        />
      </div>
      <h3>{onBreak ? "Break" : "Session"}</h3>
      <h3>{formatTime(displayTime)}</h3>
      <div className="timeButtons">
        <button onClick={controlTime} className="timeButtons">
          {timerOn ? (
            <i className="material-icons">pause</i>
          ) : (
            <i className="material-icons">play_arrow</i>
          )}
        </button>
        <button className="timeButtons">
          <i className="material-icons" onClick={resetTime}>
            autorenew
          </i>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The issue I am having with this is when the session Time reaches zero, it should turn the onBreak variable true and start counting the down the break time and change the h3 from session to break. Instead what happens is just the session time repeated. The issue is more than likely in the controlTime function where the issue resides but it isnt immediately obvious to me